# Windows.Storage in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

[Window.Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx) namespace is available only for Windows 8, so I cannot use KnownFolders class. Is there any other way to scan the user hard disk for Music/Video/Picture files in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration. For example

```
string music = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

The `SpecialFolders` assume that the user has placed the relevant media in the correct folder (e.g. the user has his/her music in the `My Music` folder).

If you want to access Windows 7 Libraries themselves, then you can use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). There's an [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-7-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference) explaining how you can use it.